# Unity Touch Input Camera Follow Jumpy

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, camera

I am trying to create a RTS style game with a camera system similar to Warcraft/Starcraft and the like.  I am making the game for Android/iOS.  As of now I found two ways to make the camera go where I want it to with touch input.  The problem is that either way the camera will move as it should for about a second, then slow down significantly like it is stuck, then speed up again.  This process continues and repeats as long as the user is moving the camera.  I have tried to put my code in an Update(), FixedUpdate(), and LateUpdate() function.  None of this seems to help.  I have included a link below to some code which includes both methods, one of which is commented out.  As for the reference to "cameraGuide" in the comment near the top, that is an empty game object I placed at (0,0,0) and made the camera as a child of it.  In one of the methods the camera must have the script so that when i use transform.localPosition it refers to the cameras position.  In the other method the script must be on the empty game object because that is what is actually translated around.

I should also mention that this only occurs when I test my app while it is installed on the Android device itself.  When I use Unity Remote to my device it never happens.  I have an HTC One M8 running Android 4.4.2.

here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

float dragSpeed = 3f;
Vector3 movement = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
Vector2 deltaPosition;

//script should be on cameraGuide for this code

void Update() {

    if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
        if (Input.touchCount == 1) {

            switch (Input.GetTouch(0).phase) {
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                    break;
                case TouchPhase.Moved:
                    deltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;

                    movement.x = -deltaPosition.x;
                    movement.z = -deltaPosition.y;

                    transform.Translate((movement.x) * dragSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, movement.z * dragSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

                    //if (transform.position.z >= 450 && (movement.z > 0 || movement.x < 0)) {
                    //  transform.Translate(0, 0, 0, Space.Self);
                    //} else {
                    //transform.Translate((movement.x) * dragSpeed, 0, movement.z * dragSpeed, Space.Self);
                    //}
                    break;
                case TouchPhase.Ended:
                    break;
            }
        } else if (Input.touchCount == 2) {
            Debug.Log("pinching");
        }
    }
}


//script should be on the camera for this code


//float dragSpeed = 5f;
//  Vector3 movement = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
//  Vector2 deltaPosition;

//  void Update() {

//      if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
//          if (Input.touchCount == 1) {

//              switch (Input.GetTouch(0).phase) {
//                  case TouchPhase.Began:
//                      break;
//                  case TouchPhase.Moved:
//                      deltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;

//                      movement.x = transform.localPosition.x - deltaPosition.x;
//                      movement.y = transform.localPosition.y;
//                      movement.z = transform.localPosition.z - deltaPosition.y;

//                      StartCoroutine(TransitionCamera());

//                      //transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, movement, dragSpeed);
//                      //transform.Translate((movement.x) * dragSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, movement.z * dragSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

//                      break;
//                  case TouchPhase.Ended:
//                      break;
//              }
//          } else if (Input.touchCount == 2) {
//              Debug.Log("pinching");
//          }
//      }
//  }

//  IEnumerator TransitionCamera() {
//      var t = 0f;

//      if (t < 1) {
//          t += Time.deltaTime;
//          transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localPosition, movement, t * dragSpeed);
//          yield return null;


//      }
//  }
```

}

Thank you for any help.

Comment: code has to go *inside the question itself*, links break